# Open a query inside while loop on another query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, while-loop

I need to open a query inside a **while loop** on another query, so that it's driven by the results of the second query.

```
$r=new COM("ADODB.Recordset");

$g=new COM("ADODB.Recordset");

$g->Open("SELECT * FROM question ORDER BY ID;",$db);

while ($g->EOF == FALSE){

    $ID=$g->Fields["ID"]->value;

    $r->Open("SELECT * FROM Answers WHERE Username='".$_GET["Username"]."' AND questionID=".$ID.";",$db);

    $g->MoveNext();
}
```

and It doesn't work.. it's ok when i put `$r->open(...)` outside... but I need to use the result of the first query in it..

Comment: "it doesn't work..." how does it not work? is it giving an error? is it a blank white screen? is it giving you incorrect/incomplete results?

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'com_exception' with message '<b>Source:</b> ADODB.Recordset<br/><b>Description:</b> Operation is not allowed when the object is open

Comment: Are you sure you are supposed to make queries using $r->Open?  Seems like you're opening a new connection to the database each time you make a new query.  A better approach would be to open 1 connection, and then make queries using $r->Execute instead. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.com.php for more details. Or you could avoid the need to do more than 1 query by doing a join, as I suggested in my answer.

Comment: @dognose it's databse connection 
`$sc = "C:\\Users\\a\\Desktop\\xampplite\\htdocs\\X\\Surveys.mdb";
$cn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" . $sc . ";";
$db = new COM("ADODB.Connection");
$db->Open($sc);`

@stephen It's working on other pages (I'm using ms access)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you combine the two queries into one by using a join?

```
"select Answers.ID, Question.ID from Answers inner join Questions where Questions.ID=Answers.QuestionID and Answers.Username=" . $_GET["Username"]
```

Combine the two tables by joining the answers and questions that are related to each other.